# How data arrives from a gps tracker by gprs to a node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gps

I created an application to show the location of a gps in real time using gprs. This application uses node.js. I have already created all the methods and in tests it works correctly. I set up the gps to an external gps server and send the data correctly. Now I configured it with my server and happens is I have the socket.io with open listening but the data does not arrive. Could someone help me to see why the data does not arrive or if it is arriving because I cannot read it?

This is the code to listen:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://34.226.95.13:5050', { 'forceNew': true });
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})


socket.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        var location = JSON.stringify(data);
        socket.emit('data', item);
  });

});
```

Thanks

Comment: how you managed to get data from gps device using node js, can you share it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was searching the internet a lot and found a way to receive the information only with the DATA parameter, but I went a little further and found that the server returned an answer like this: ##, imei: 359xxxxxxxxxxxx, A;

Then, I kept investigating and had to respond to the device with LOAD, after doing my own development I found a repository that has everything very well organized and is the best to use.

To install you need to enter the following command in the console:

```
npm install gpstracker
```

And next, create index.js and copy this code:

```
var gpstracker = require("gpstracker");

var server = gpstracker.create().listen(5050, function(){
   console.log('listening your gps trackers on port', 5050);
});

server.trackers.on("connected", function(tracker){

  console.log("tracker connected with imei:", tracker.imei);

  tracker.on("help me", function(){
    console.log(tracker.imei + " pressed the help button!!".red);
  });

  tracker.on("position", function(position){
    console.log("tracker {" + tracker.imei +  "}: lat",
                        position.lat, "lng", position.lng);
  });

  tracker.trackEvery(10).seconds();
});
```

Thanks